# How do I make a query to cast the value in a column for all partitioned tables in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partition

I am curious if there is a way to query and write to all the partitioned tables in big query. I wanted to cast a single column to a different datatype and apply it to all the values across the partitions in a big query table.

i.e.

```
select cast(nums as STRING) from `project_id.dataset.table`
```

And have it written back out to all the values in the column across the table. Is there a straightforward way to do this in bigquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `deleting.part`
PARTITION BY day 
AS
SELECT DATE('2018-01-01') day, 2 i
UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2018-01-02'), 3
```

[image]

Now, let's change `i` from `INT64` to `FLOAT64`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `deleting.part`
PARTITION BY day 
AS
SELECT * REPLACE(CAST(i AS FLOAT64) AS i)
FROM `deleting.part`
```

[image]

Cost: Full table scan.